# 3" shaft high wear

Tags: shafts

A 3" drive shaft 27" long with keyway.

**Application**

- 40 ft long mixing tank
- Limestone 40% mix with water
- RPM 60, temperature 70 °F - 200 °F
- Shaft supported by hard iron static bearing
- 1045-1144 5% failed, within 6 months the limestone will grind the
  shaft from 3" to under 2"

**Next test**

- 4140 induction heat treat only where the shaft and bearing makes
  contact, about 0.25" depth to a hardness of 600 Brinell.
- Hard iron bearing 500 Brinell.

Is this a good solution?

Comment: is the shaft wear only at the bearing?